# Clear input box on click with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code that I'm trying to wrok into my website to clear a textbox with a default value, when a user click on it, the default value should clear out so that the user can enter his/her value. Here is what I have but I'm not sure if its correct since its not working. I just started on JQuery

```
   $(document).ready(function()
  {
        $('#startDateBox').click(function()
        { 
            if(('#startDateBox')=='Beginning')

            {
             $('#startDateBox').val(''); 
            }

         })
   });​
```

Comment: Can you define what is 'not working'?

Comment: Well, `if(('#startDateBox')=='Beginning')` will *always* be false...

Comment: When I debug it, when I click in the box, it doesn't clear out the default value, which is the word Begining. I feel like I'm missing something in my code

Comment: $('#startDateBox').val(), if 'beginning' is the text inside it..

Comment: `<input id="startDateBox" type="text" placeholder="Beginning" />`, HTML5 has this built in ?

Comment: When writing javascript always always put the { at the end of the line, not the begining of the next line.  Putting it at the end can cause your code to work incorrectly. Watch Douglas Crockfords videos (search youtube)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the first `.val()`, and the `$` in front of the `('#startDateBox')` on the same line.
You could also use `$(this)` to reference the textbox, as within that function `this` refers to the textbox DOM element itself. Wrapping it with the jQuery function `$()` gives you access to all the framework's goodies.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#startDateBox').click(function(){  
         if($(this).val() == 'Beginning')
                 ^^^^^^ Here
         {
             $(this).val(''); 
         }
    })
});​
```

Comment: and missing `$` in that line

Answer (score 3):

You're wrong in this part:

```
 if(('#startDateBox')=='Beginning')
```

First, you missing `$`.
Second, I think you want compare the `startDateBox` value, then use `val()`.

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
  {
        $('#startDateBox').click(function()
        { 
            if($('#startDateBox').val()=='Beginning')
            {
             $('#startDateBox').val(''); 
            }
         })
   });​
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for HTML5 browsers use this

```
 <input type="text" id="Beginning" placeholder="Beginning"  />

if($('#startDateBox').val() =='Beginning')
```

this is the line that needs to be changed

also

```
        $('#startDateBox').on("focus", function()
        { 
          // code here
```

the click will not handle hitting tab until that text box is focused

Comment: fixed , the placeholder attribute handles all that for you as well in newer browsers

Answer (score 0):

Well, `if(('#startDateBox')=='Beginning')` will *always* be false...

I think you meant something more like:

```
if($('#startDateBox').val() == 'Beginning')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very small jquery plugin for this purpose recently:

https://gist.github.com/rmcvey/5136582

```
$('#input').placeholder("Placeholder Text");

if($('#input').val() === $('#input').placeholder()){ return false; }
```